# Why isn't this number random?

Tags: c, random

For the following piece of code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    x = rand()%100;
    printf("The Random Number is: %i", x);

return 0;
}
```

It always seems to print the random number as 83. Why is this?

Comment: Because you didn't initialize the PRNG. You need to set the seed based on something that varies, such as the time. But I recommend avoiding the integrated c PRNG completely.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: What is the 'PRNG'? You are talking to a complete C n00b here.

Comment: I just want to repeat that most implementations of `rand` are very bad and break down even in simple simulations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most [random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) are repeatable. You need to seed the generator before using it which you typically do using the system time.

```
#include <time.h>
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: Note that initializing the PRNG from the time is not always ok: that gives you a predictable seed. In particular, cryptography requires unpredictable random numbers, but the C library doesn't deliver that anyway.

Comment: Note that merely using time tends to fail miserably on highly threaded systems (like a web server), where two different threads might run at the same time (within the accuracy of `time()`).

Answer (score 6):

Obligatory XKCD reference:

[image]

As people have said, you need to seed the *pseudo* random number generator properly.

The trouble is, it still only generates ***pseudo*** random numbers.  Most "true" random number generators require access to some physical phenomenon that is [random in nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) (for example, clock skews or temperature fluctuations).

Otherwise, the XKCD reference is not too far from the truth. Nor is Dilbert.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like the pop-culture references!

Comment: @jones: You're welcome!  Random numbers are a slippery slope once you start looking into them.  The xkcd and Dilbert comics obviously know this and draw a line in the sand early on. :-)

Comment: @downvoter: Why? Downvoting without explanation is --- at best --- rude or, in my opinion, cowardly. Nothing in my post is, as far as I can see dishonest or not answering the question (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

Because the pseudo-random number generator used by **`rand`** is always initialized with the same seed.

In order to initialize it with a different seed, you can use the **`srand`** function, and initialize it as, say, `srand(time(NULL))`.

Answer (score 3):

Because 83 is a random number, isn't it ?

More seriously, it is useful to have programs providing a repeatable behavior so by default, rand always returns the same sequence of numbers if you don't change the seed.

Comment: +1 for one good reason why you *don't* always want random random numbers!

Answer (score 1):

Seed the random number generator by including `<time.h>` and calling `srand(time(0));`  (edited thanks to my commenters)

Comment: @R. Time is of type time_t.  I don't believe that's guaranteed to be an unsigned int, though it usually is.

Comment: @jonsca: `time_t` is guaranteed to be an arithmetic type, so it'll be converted to the right type anyway. (If `time_t` was allowed to be something else, the cast wouldn't work, so it's useless either way.)

Comment: @Gilles I had always gotten warnings with it before, but for some reason they're not popping up.  I'll have to look into that.  Thanks for making an actual statement.

Comment: @jonsca: Rule of thumb for casts in C: if you get a compiler warning and adding a cast silences the warning, you're fixing the symptom and keeping the problem. In most cases that need casts, the compiler isn't smart enough to warn you.

Comment: In principle this could be undefined behavior either with or without a cast, since `time_t` is allowed to be a floating-point type, and the current time could have a value too large to fit into an `unsigned int`. So as Gilles says, any warning from the compiler that's suppressed by a cast might actually be telling you something theoretically important, for example that your code will stop working at some deadline. Admittedly, with the Unix epoc and a 32-bit int, that deadline is in 2106, so perhaps not of much practical interest...

Comment: @Steve I'll keep it in mind for my 100+ birthday :)  You raise a good point.

Comment: @Steve: Is conversion from floating point types to *unsigned* integer types undefined if the value does not fit?

Comment: @R..: yes it is (6.3.1.4/1). `unsigned int` is "an integer type other than _Bool", and footnote 50 points out that the modulus need not be taken as it would be when converting from an integer type.

Comment: Wow, learned something new. Yet another reason not to use floating point for integer values...

Answer (score 0):

You can not generate a random number which is truly random until and unless your random number generator has access to a truly random physical phenomenon as quoted earlier by peter. But for a general use you can use C's standard library functions for generating random numbers. Here is a sample code for generating random number between two limits(max and min):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MIN 1
#define MAX 5
#define QUANTITY 5

int main()
{
     int i;
     //stores the time in seconds
     time_t seconds;
     //getting the system time
     time(&seconds);
     //initializing the random generator with system time
     //as the seed value
     srand((long)seconds);

     for(i = 0; i < QUANTITY; i++)
     {
           printf("%f\t",((float)rand())/RAND_MAX*(MAX-MIN)+MIN);
     }
     printf("\n");

     return 0;
}
```